# Is it possible the get the original (best) audio quality when using avconv?

Tags: audio, conversion, ffmpeg

In Feb 2011 I had a similar question: [ffmpeg and libmp3lame produces bad audio quality?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/ffmpeg-and-libmp3lame-produces-bad-audio-quality)
Now I'd like to know if it is possible to the get the original audio quality from a (flash) video? Every time I convert a video, the quality is worse than the original quality, not much worse but you can hear the difference. These are my attempts:

```
   avconv -i ~/"$2.flv" -acodec libmp3lame -c:v libx264 -qscale 1 -aq 1 -q 1 -vol 100 -ab 196608 ~/"$2.avi"
```

I tried to use the best quality -qscale 1, aq 1 and so on. I even tried to use **-same_quant**, I already tried **-codec copy**, shown in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40321/how-get-the-best-quality-when-convertingfrom-mp4-to-avi-with-ffmpeg) thread, but then the quality is not better but even worse and I don't see any video then. Is there a way to achieve that? By the way, I don't care about the output format.

**UPDATE**
I made some test by downloading a video from YT and listen to it both on YT and on my local machine. I didn't convert the video, I just listened to a flv file itself and determined that the local quality is even worse than the file on YT. So I'm not sure if this is really an avconv problem. I wonder where this quality difference between the stream from YT and the downloaded file from TY come from. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you supply the complete, uncut console output for your command?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your update: depending on how you're downloading the video, you may not be getting the best quality version that YouTube is hosting. If you're using [clive](http://clive.sourceforge.net) (or [cclive](http://cclive.sourceforge.net)), `-f best` will get the best it can.

If you want to reliably not lose any data when pulling audio out of a video file, convert it to .wav or ensure you're not re-encoding.

Comment: Thanks, but this tool doesn't work:
verify video link ...
error: Unknown error (http/403)
 (in cleanup) cannot access `DESTROY' field in class clive::Video at /usr/share/perl5/clive/App.pm line 106

Comment: Sorry, my fault for recommending clive when cclive has replaced it. Use cclive instead.

Comment: I will try it but atm, it doesn't work either. Obviously YT changed something. I get this error: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cclive/ticket/20

Btw: youtube-dl doesn't work either due to YT changes. I think I have to wait some days until next try.

Comment: Oh man. Bummer. Thanks for pointing that out.